# How should I encrypt passwords for API access without showing off the algorithm to the client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, public-key-encryption

I have a REST API (.net) which for the initial login requires the password to be encrypted (RSA with OAEP).  The reason was to obscure the users passwords from local logs.

Performing this encryption with javascript is complicated and I would need to let the client know the public key.  The end user would be able to reverse engineer the encryption method then could use it to brute-force (or worse) access.  So why bother, right (it is SSL Secure).

Thing is, I still need that password to be encrypted.  Should I have some sort of encryption service at the server side that gives me the password to throw at the token endpoint?  Why not have the service just log in for me then return the token.  How should I proceed?

Thanks ^_^

Comment: Why not use an API key for the user instead of their password? User would log into your site to generate said key, which would then be kept secret on their end. The user should have the ability to regenerate the API key if they believe their key has been breached.

Comment: As for _"The end user would be able to reverse engineer the encryption method then could use it to brute-force (or worse) access."_: if one assumes that's feasible, then why would one still assume TLS to be secure? (That said, I'm not saying that you should not drop the local encryption of the password.)

Comment: We do use tokens.  I'm talking about the initial login.
Arjan: ikr!? I really dislike that the project lead went for such an elaborate encryption if all they want to do is hide a plain-text password from the local logs

Comment: Just curious: what are "local logs"? Logs on the user's system, like a browser's network traffic tab (even the HTTP `Authorization: Basic` header obscures credentials a bit using Base64, but mainly to ensure that funny characters don't introduce errors) or some user's server logs? Or logs on your systems? (For the latter, I'd not want encrypted passwords in my logs either, as that would tell which users use the same password, unless some more information is encrypted. But above all: those who can access _your_ logs might also know your private key, so could decrypt the password.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a general authentication question. You can solve it like you would solve user authentication. Think of it this way:

When a user signs-in into your app, they provide their data on the client, and then it is validated on the server. In order for them to stay logged in, they get some sort of token, either via a Cookie session, JWT or whatever. Which is then saved on the client and sent on each request to the server in order to verify they are authenticated.

The above is how websites can show "registered users only" content. By validating a previously given token on each new request.

Now, applying this method to your REST Api. A user needs to request a token (which *should not* be your master password, but a uniquely generated one, in a per-user basis), and then save it locally for X amount of time. Every time the user makes a request to the API they send that token, which is validated.

This is also how normal APIs do it. You will need a token or some sort either way. If it's really sensitive information you're showing, the token should update every now and then (from minutes to days depending on how sensitive). You keep a record of valid tokens in your server. That way, if any token is "stolen", then it will only be valid for a small amount of time.

Comment: Yeah we use access and refresh tokens.  They expire in relatively short enough times.  So do you reckon I should identify web users (easily done via a header) and use a simpler or no password encryption?  That would work for me.  The iPads are able to encrypt the RSA with OAEP much easier than I can in js

Comment: Yup. That's how it's done. If a user is authenticated you can assume they're safe (with short-lived tokens ofc). The reason is that nothing you put on the client will ever be safe. So encrypting it, or doing any shenanigans can be broken by a smart-enough attacker.